# Delay or error performing segue from TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have seen two similar questions here but none of their answers really helped me.
I have a **tableView** of comments and I want to perform a segue to a detail of the comment (kind of like twitter does, if you click on a tweet you have a detail view of it). However **the information given to the detail view is the penultimate row selected and not the last selected**. And if you only select one, the segue wont be even performed.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail_segue", sender: indexPath)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "detail_segue"){
        let row = (sender as! NSIndexPath).row;
        let commentForSegue = self.AOS[row]
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentDetailVC
        destinationVC.detail_title = commentForSegue.titulo_comment
        destinationVC.detail_body = commentForSegue.cuerpo_comment
        destinationVC.detail_date = commentForSegue.fecha_comment
        destinationVC.detail_num_agree = String(commentForSegue.num_agrees)
        destinationVC.detail_num_disagree = String(commentForSegue.num_disagrees)
        destinationVC.detail_agreed = commentForSegue.agreed
    } 
}
```

I've tried with and without the `dispatch_async` both on the `prepareForSegue` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but it doesnt work. I've also tried doing all the work from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but no success either.

Thanks!!

Comment: The behaviour you are describing does sound like you are trying to segue from a background thread but looking at your code you are accounting for that. Check that the segue that is delayed is not getting called via another method (i.e. not from didDeselectRowAtIndexPath). If it is getting a rogue call to segue, that call may be on a background thread.

Comment: Can you share your project in GitHub to help you?

Comment: @Damo the segue its just called from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @PabloDuque See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to call the segue in the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and you're calling it from the method `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` exist a little difference between both, but are some tips to get the last cell tapped too, see the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // the identifier of the segue is the same you set in the Attributes Inspector
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail_segue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   if(segue.identifier == "detail_segue"){
       // this is the way of get the indexPath for the selected cell
       let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
       let row = indexPath.row

       let commentForSegue = self.AOS[row]
       let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentDetailVC
       destinationVC.detail_title = commentForSegue.titulo_comment
       destinationVC.detail_body = commentForSegue.cuerpo_comment
       destinationVC.detail_date = commentForSegue.fecha_comment
       destinationVC.detail_num_agree = String(commentForSegue.num_agrees)
       destinationVC.detail_num_disagree = String(commentForSegue.num_disagrees)
       destinationVC.detail_agreed = commentForSegue.agreed
   } 
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Omg.... That retardness of mine, I'll change it and get back to you but it looks like ur answer should fix it. Thanks a lot